# lowercasing XML tags

Tags: xml, perl

I have two sets of XML documents, one with uppercase tags and one with lowercase, so I'm trying to write a Perl program that lowercases all the tags in the second set.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
my $filename;
my @filenames = glob ("*.xml");
my $FH;
my $lcCapture;
my $row;
my $match;


foreach $filename (@filenames) {
    open ($FH, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
}

  while ($row = <$FH>) {
      chomp $row;

      if ($row =~ m/(?:<\/?([A-Z]+)>)/) {
      $match = $1;
      $lcCapture = lc $match;
      $match =~ s/$match/$lcCapture/g;
  } 
      {no warnings;
      print "$row\n";}


 }
```

but I just can't figure out what the problem might be. I've already solved the problem with XSLT. But I want my Perl program to work now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Perl stream editing capabilities:

```
perl -pe 's/<\/?[^>]+>/\L$&/g' file.xml
```

This solution will only lowercase the tags, and not what is enclosed by them.

Comment: Thanks, That worked like a dream. Can you explain the last section of that substitution? This bit: `\L$&`

Comment: `\L` is a modifier that turns any string that follows it into lowercase. `$&` contains the most recent match. You can read more about them here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should use an XML parser, but a regex might be fine in a limited situation like yours.  Your problem is that you perform the substitution on the wrong variable.  Change:

```
$match =~ s/$match/$lcCapture/g;
```

to:

```
$row =~ s/$match/$lcCapture/g;
```